# Unable to search in Content Manager (503 Error)

Tags: 2011, content-manager

I have just upgraded my version of Tridion from 5.3 to 2011. When I try to perform a search within the Content Manager Explorer I get the following error message (in the Message Center)

```
(80040356) The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
Unable to get the list of search results.
Error occured while processing the request: Service Unavailable.

System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SolrClient.ProcessResponse(HttpWebRequest,Boolean,Boolean,String&)
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SolrClient.Post(String,String,String&)
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SolrClient.Query(String,Int32,Nullable`1,String&)
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SearchQueryEngine.GetSearchResultsFromSolr(SearchQueryData,Int32,Nullable`1) 

Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SearchQueryEngine.GetSearchResultsFromSolr(SearchQueryData,Int32,Nullable`1)
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SearchQueryEngine.GetSearchResults(SearchQueryData,Int32,Int32)
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.ComWrapper.SearchQueryEngineFacade.GetSearchResults(Int32,Int32)
SearchBLST.GetListData
SearchBLST.GetSearchResults
SearchBLST.GetSearchResultsEx 
Search.GetSearchResultsEx
```

Opening Firebug when performing the search I get a `500 Internal Server Error` when accessing `http://myserver/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/Lists.svc/GetListSearch`.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

I'm pretty sure search was working correctly before I changed the users that my Tridion services run as. I changed all the services from the default `NETWORK_SERVICE` (I think) to individual user accounts such as `MYDOMAIN\tcmbuscon` and `MYDOMAIN\tcmsearchhost` etc. as documented in the Tridion Installation manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is the solution to my specific problem. If you are experiencing something similar you should contact SDL support and follow their advice or you may void your warranty.

After contacting SDL Support I was able to solve my problem.

1. Stop both the `TcmSearchHost` service and the `TcmSearchIndexer` service.
2. Start the `TcmSearchHost` service and checked the most recent jetty log (C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\log\xxxx_xx_xx.jetty.log). This shoudl show an `Access Denied` error for a file in `C:\Windows\Temp\Jetty_0_0_0_0_8983_apache.solr.war____u5n80a\...`.
3. Give your search and indexer users read, write and modify access to `C:\Windows\Temp\Jetty_0_0_0_0_8983_apache.solr.war____u5n80a`
4. Restart the search and indexer services.

Comment: Yes, support is always useful, Generally you should have your MTS user have read/write access to Windows Temp folder and on the similar note generally you do have your search and indexer user as MTS user. So unless you have not played with it, you will not have such issue.

Comment: @PankajGaur In the official Tridion 2011 documentation it mentions setting the services to run under certain user accounts (tcmsearchhost, tcmbuscon etc etc) so that's what I did.

Answer (score 4):

Is your search service running on the local CMS (TCMSearchHost.Exe)?

Do you get 500 errors on all models that are of /TCM54/ ? - if so that could mean your com+ service isn't running.

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\bin\x64\TcmSearchHost.exe` is running on my server. How do I check that my COM+ Service is running?

Comment: @KevinBrydon - go to > administrative tools > component services > - expand down through component services, your local machine to com+ services - here you can right click on the sdl tridion items and stop and start them as need  be

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. In the `COM+ Applications` I right click on `SDL Tridion Content Manager` and click `Start`. My problem is still there. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Check for following:

1. In your CMS server, go Server Explorer -> Configuration -> Local User & Groups and ensure a User group SDL User Search (or something like that) is available - It get configured during your installation. And further ensure it is part of the Administrative group
2. Check whether your MTS user is a part of this SDL User Search Group
3. Ensure your MTS user is same with which you have performed the installation
4. Go to the CMS server and execute `http://localhost:8983/Tridion or http://[cms host name]:8983/Tridion` and see if it is working - else go through the installation manual to make it work or let us know the error you are facing
5. check for following settings in the SDL Tridion Content Manager Configuration MMC and ensure they all are correct:
   [image]

Ensure that all of the above points should work as expected.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Steps 1, 2 and 3 are ok. When I try step 4 I get a `503. Problem accessing /Tridion. SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE`

Comment: Two other points. 1. My Content Manager Snap In is different to yours. It has two sub folders `Indexer Service Settings` and `Query Engine Settings`. 2. My `Tridion Content Manager Search Host` runs under `MYDOMAIN\tcmsearchhost`.

Comment: Regarding (4) - It looks like the issue with your installation - follow the installation manual and re-verify whether your have missed any step - or take help from SDL Tridion Support. May be you can try running your Tridion Services including the one you mentioned above by either MTS User or Network service.

Regarding (5), I have put up this screen shot from SDL Live content, looks like it is not updated here - You are right though as you mentioned for two folders in SDL Tridion 2011. In each of them these folders these 4 setting mentioned above would be there.

Comment: Thanks. I contacted Tridion support yesterday. Just waiting on a reply.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please verify port 8983 is open (no firewalls) and that is controlled by the TcmSearchHost Process.

The steps are:

1. In a Command Prompt Window run   ***netstat -a -n -o***
2. You can see the process ID (list as PID) of the process using tcp port 8983. Take note of that number (let's say PID_NUMBER)
3. Run:  ***tasklist /svc /FI "PID eq PID_NUMBER"***

A working system should be output something similar to:

Image Name                    PID  Process

========================= ======== ======================

TcmSearchHost.exe             1960 TcmSearchHost

Hope it helps.

Comment: As stated above they are not able to access the URL even from the CMS server itself.

Comment: I've run what you said and get the correct "working system" output.

Comment: Could you try the following to make sure the service is starting without problems?
1. Stop the Tridion Content Manager Search Host from Windows Services.
2. From a command prompt go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\solr-jetty (the installation path may differ from your system) and run the batch start.bat
3. If there are no errors in the startup process you should be able to access http://localhost:8983/
Note the above URL does not have Tridion in it.

I had a similar problem and the issue was with Java. For some reason Windows was starting the service without errors.